# CKFinder opens a blank window, with no errors

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor, ckfinder

I added a CKFinder button on my website that calls this function on click:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                function BrowseServer(a)
                {
                    var which=a;
                    var finder = new CKFinder() ;
                    finder.basePath = 'ckfinder/' ;
                    finder.selectActionFunction = SetFileField ;
                    finder.selectFunctionData = a ;
                    finder.popup() ;
                }

                function SetFileField( fileUrl, data )
                {
                    document.getElementById(which).value = fileUrl ;
                    insertTextAtCursor(getObj('message'), fileUrl);
                }

            </script>
```

This opens up a blank window. When I view the source, this is what I see:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"><html><head><title>CKFinder 2</title><style type="text/css">body, html, iframe, #ckfinder { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }</style></head><body></body></html>
```

I have enabled error_reporting in the ckfinder/config.php and connector file. Yet am not seeing any error.

Surprisingly, the ckfinder works with my ckeditor integration but doesnt work when called with Javascript from a button.

What may be the problem?

Comment: what happens when you remove   finder.popup() ;

Comment: `"called with Javascript from a button."` What does that code look like?